# Beginner Haskell question: how do I find indices in Haskell (manually using recursion without using findIndices)

Tags: haskell, recursion, indices

I have a Haskell homework exercise to manually re-create `findIndices` using recursion.

I've simplified the problem by hard-coding a cons 0 each time it finds an index that meets the criteria:

```
positions :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] ->[Integer] 
positions p [] = []
positions p (x:xs) 
| p x = 0 : positions p xs
    | otherwise = positions p xs
```

But instead of outputting a 0 in each position of the output list, I want it to output the index but I cannot work out how to do this using a count variable.

I've tried to simplify this by just outputting the index to every item but can't work this out either so I've got:

```
pos :: [a] -> [Integer]
pos [] = []
pos (x:xs) = 0 : pos xs
```

which returns a 0 for every item in the list so [2,3,4,5] returns [0,0,0,0] as expected but I can't work out how to make it return [0,1,2,3]

I can make it count how many items are in the list but I can't work out how to put the count variable into the list.

```
pos1 :: [a] -> Integer 
pos1 [] = 0
pos1 (x:xs) = let count = pos1 xs in count+1
```

Any help in "Haskell for Dummies" language would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: Hint: you can zip the indices with the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. I'll focus on a basic approach, even if better ones exist which exploit the library list functions.

You wrote you want a counter variable. So, start by defining a function which takes that counter (variable `index` below) as an additional argument. Following the code you posted, we get:

```
positionsIndex :: Integer -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Integer] 
positionsIndex index p []     = ...
positionsIndex index p (x:xs) = ...
```

After that, we can define the wanted function by providing the additional argument

```
positions :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Integer] 
positions p xs = positionsIndex 0 p xs
```

The `0` above initializes the counter argument to the first position.

Now, you should finish `positionsIndex`, by suitably adapting your already posted code. Note that you will have to pass the counter to each recursive call to `positionsIndex`.

---

You can make `positionsIndex` a local function adapting the following. Be careful to make all the related equations perfectly aligned.

```
positions :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Integer] 
positions p xs = ...
   where
   positionsIndex :: Integer -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Integer] 
   positionsIndex index p []     = ...
   positionsIndex index p (x:xs) = ...
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering, unfortunately, I cannot change the first line, that's been given to us as part of the question, the first line has to be positions :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] ->[Integer] - we cannot change it to Integer -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] ->[Integer] - is there a solution using that first line?

Comment: @theWhiteKnight Note that `positions :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Integer]` is unchanged.

Comment: @theWhiteKnight You can write `positionsIndex` below `positions`, if required. That does not prevent you to call it from `positions`. You could also make it a local definition using a `where`, delimiting its scope.

Comment: @chi - Could you explain how I could do this in one function with a where statement?  I've tried to work out how where works and although I've followed some simple examples, I can't apply it in this situation.  Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: @theWhiteKnight: please accept the answer if it answers your question. Thank you.

Comment: I would if I knew how to.  I've just searched 'accept' and can't find it on this page - there's no button for 'accept'.  Also, do you mean accept this Haskell answer (above) or the answer that you gave to my Prolog question today?  If you can tell me which answer you would like me to accept and how to do it, I'll gladly accept the answer.

Comment: @theWhiteKnight At the beginning of the answer you wish to accept you should see a grey checkmark on the left side. Clicking it makes it green, marking the answer as the accepted one. (Note that you can only accept one answer, so choose the best one, and only accept if the answer indeed answered your question) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work